# Making a delay function in minecraft function 1.12

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make some delay inside function, and i've made this:

```
scoreboard objectives add run stat.playOneMinute

scoreboard players set @a[score_run_min=40] run 0

execute @e[score_run_min=10,score_run=10] ~ ~ ~ say 3
execute @e[score_run_min=20,score_run=20] ~ ~ ~ say 2
execute @e[score_run_min=30,score_run=30] ~ ~ ~ say 1
execute @e[score_run_min=40,score_run=40] ~ ~ ~ say START!
```

I set /gamerule doLoopFunction to this file and run it with /function.
In my imagination it will like say 4 times and reset then say again.
But it just resets the timer and the timer runs overtime. When i activate the function again at exactly time it says.
Now how can i make it run like my imagination.Thanks.

Comment: You set it to 0 in every tick. You could instead only set it to 0 when you want to start the countdown, whenever that is. Not in the function.

Comment: @FabianRöling i've set /gamerule doFunctionLoop to this file, mean it will always reset to 0. But when i run the file, it just reset once and still run

Comment: What output do you get? And what output do you want?

Comment: @FabianRöling i want it says in order: 3 2 1 START!. Every blank part will change to a different line

Comment: Then I would suggest scrapping your entire function that you have so far and just using four functions with one `say` command each and `schedule function <name> <time>` at the end.